# What does the music notation "/ / / /" mean in a music drum score?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, repeats, drum-kits

I have a **drum score sheet music** with **4/4** time signature in which the following portion is present.
[image: Drum score].

---

Now, I am **unable to understand the symbols** in the bar:

[image: Drum bar]

Also, **what to repeat** for the second `Repeat 1` bar?

---

*P.S.*

1. I have removed the actual score to avoid copyright violation.
2. Please also note the bar numbers.
3. The actual sheet music is from this link: http://www.drumeo.com/blog/break-sticks-play-along/

Comment: There should be a legend defining the meaning of each of symbols.

Comment: @davidstrachan: Okay the actual sheet music is from this link: http://www.drumeo.com/blog/break-sticks-play-along/

Comment: The 4 slashes represent Free Fills or Solos

Comment: This is fine, but for future reference you shouldn't need to blank anything out when the excerpt is just a few bars.  Given that this is for educational and analytical purposes, and you've sourced it, it falls well within Fair Use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Counting Verse 1 from bar 5. Bar 5 & 6 are repeated 7 times to lead to bar 21. = 16 bars
2. Bar 21 is repeated 6 times Then  the 4 slashes **/** are played  solo or freeform = 8 bars.
3. These 8 bars are then repeated to come to bar 37

Comment: That's the only possibility. But I don't agree with the strange notations for the two repetitions. Is this the standard way to do so?

Comment: I have not seen this before, but I assume the author's software has no function for repeat signs and is just using text instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to keep it really simple: The measure in question is to be played 'free' or 'fill'. You can do whatever feels right musically to you, then continue on as you were playing before.